# vector subscript error when downsampling point clouds

Tags: visual-studio-2013, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

I am compiling a demo (given by the tutorial) of using RANSAC to do the registration of two point clouds. 
Here is the URL of the demo code 
http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/alignment_prerejective.php

The code is compiled successfully in VS2013 with PCL 1.7.2 (all in one version). I have this kind of error when running the Debug build 
[image]

Comment: did you press retry to debug the application to see which line causes the problem?

Comment: Yes, retry was pressed and continue also after this pop-up. The program has already been compiled after a few modification but I really did not figured out what the problem is.